# How to merge two frequency count dictionary - unix cmd?

Tags: terminal, dictionary

I'm having two frequency count dictionary, I have tried to merge them using join/sort  cmd but always getting wrong output or different frequency count.
I want to join them together, adding +1 if the word exist, and the new word count 1

```
  7 umslipped
  1 umslippersmouthwashand
  3 umslobagas
 35 umslopogaas
  5 (umslopogaas
 15 (umslopogaas)
  1 umslower
  6 umsmall
  2 umsnag
  2 um[snaps
 13 umsnootchie
  2 umsnow
 84 umso
 14 um-so ##
```

The second dictionary

```
1   palpating
1   palpated
1   palpate
1   palpably
1   palpable
1   palominos
1   palomino
1   palomar
1   palmyra
1   palmy
1   palmtops
1   palmtop
1   palms
1   palmolive
1   palmists
1   palmistry
1   palmist
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `awk` to add it all up.

```
awk '{ arr[$2] += $1} END {for (key in arr) {printf "%4s %s\n", arr[key], key}}' file1 file2
```

**Explanation**

- `{ arr[$2] += $1}` set array index of our string aka `$2` to `+=` the number `$1`
- `END` When we're done
- `{for (key in arr) {printf "%4s %s\n", arr[key], key}}` Loop through it all and print it out.

**What I did to test it**

file1

```
  7 umslipped
  1 umslippersmouthwashand
  3 umslobagas
 35 umslopogaas
  5 (umslopogaas
 15 (umslopogaas)
  1 umslower
  6 umsmall
  2 umsnag
  2 um[snaps
 13 umsnootchie
  2 umsnow
 84 umso
 14 um-so ##
```

file2

```
 14 um-so ##
 84 umso
  2 umsnow
 13 umsnootchie
  2 um[snaps
  2 umsnag
  6 umsmall
  1 umslower
 15 (umslopogaas)
  5 (umslopogaas
 35 umslopogaas
  3 umslobagas
  1 umslippersmouthwashand
  7 umslipped
```

Output

```
  10 (umslopogaas
  12 umsmall
   6 umslobagas
  28 um-so
   2 umslippersmouthwashand
  30 (umslopogaas)
  70 umslopogaas
  26 umsnootchie
   4 umsnag
 168 umso
   4 um[snaps
  14 umslipped
   4 umsnow
   2 umslower
```

Comment: putting the output in the same format as the input rather than swapping around the order and adding a colon would mean that the program could be used to process data multiple times.

Comment: Thank you, but this is a dataset the format should be the same,

Comment: @ahmedsabir I updated the command to change the format to the desired outcome. I am on mobile so I will update the sample output when I'm near a computer

Comment: @ahmedsabir I updated the command and the output

Comment: @ZacharyBrady, thanks a lot, it works like a charm.